# echo json data then sleep

Tags: php, json

In my php script I want to output data to the browser then sleep() for 2 seconds before running a function. The below doesnt seem to output the json before sleeping, anyone got any ideas?

```
if ($_POST['process'] == '1') {
    // adding stuff to $data here
    }

    echo json_encode($data);
    ob_flush();
    flush();
    sleep(2);
    // Do something else
}
```

Comment: please paste complete code. in current code snippet, you missed `{` or `}`

Comment: I think you need to do `ob_start();` first, so you create a buffer what gets flushed by flush.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, this is how you do it. Basically, you close the connection and return the response to the user while apache continues to process the file...

```
ignore_user_abort(true);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
header('Connection: close');
header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($YOUR_JSON_RESPONSE));

echo $YOUR_JSON_RESPONSE;
flush();

sleep(2);
your_cool_function_to_run();
die();
```

---

Works great for quick ajax calls that need an immediate response and/or take a long time to actually do the work.

I must warn you to use this type of thing sparingly... Each time this happens a new process/thread is opened up to handle the remainder of your request. Do too many too fast and you'll run out of processes. (Depending on your setup)

Comment: +1 for the `Connection:` and `Content-Length:` headers.  I think that those, in addition to closing STDOUT should do the trick.

Comment: I've never heard of PHP script splitted across threads: do you have any reference? Also, threads and process are really different beasts

Comment: I dont have a reference.. Correct my understanding if its wrong: Each user request to PHP opens an individual process and once the closure and response is sent that process ends. When you send a response in this manner and then continue the process it spawns a new php process to handle the processing. Since, you could let that function go on for minutes after the sleep(2), then the process would hang.

Comment: Thanks phpisuber01 that worked a treat, I will also take your advice about using it sparingly, thanks again

Comment: @phpisuber01 AFAIK, Apache can run the script internally (mod_php) or relay to an external process (FCGI, which really is a pool of processes last time I checked). When using mod_php, a script may be run in the single Apache process or in a thread from a threads pool or in a process from a processes pool (which is the most common setup I've seen), depending on the MPM. However I never read that the current process halts after a call to `flush()` - and honestly I don't know how that would help, since there would always be one process running...

Comment: Thanks Raffaele, I'll have to go beat up one of the IT Ops people here in the office to learn more. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could try closing `STDOUT`, to signal to the web server that your script is done sending data to the HTTP client.

```
fclose( STDOUT);
```